Can civiDiscount be used for membership auto-renewals?
Currently we handle annual membership renewals manually -- in that members need to indicate they want to pay for another year of membership. Sometimes we offer membership discounts, and to do this, we use civiDiscount.
I'm interested in implementing auto-renewals for memberships. However, there are times when we want to offer discounts to those who opt for auto-renewal.
My question is -- is there a way to automatically apply a discount during a membership auto-renewal?

I very much doubt it for some processors as the amount to be charged is stored on the processor

If the discount is always given to those that pick auto-renew, a potential workaround would be to have two different memberships
